# Postman: Get data from JSON file in Pre-request Script

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I am trying to find a way to use data from my .json file in the pre-request script in Postman.
As you can see in the code below I am using a loop for my request. 
In my pre-request script i would like to use *"id_group":"14803,14805"* from my file Data.json instead of *id_group = ["14803","14805"];*.

Thanks

**URL:**

```
.../group/{{id_of_group}}/members
```

**Body:**

```
    {
     "id_user": {{id_user}}
    }
```

**Pre-request script:**

```
var id_group = pm.environment.get("id_group");

if (!id_group) {
    id_group = ["14803","14805"];
}   

var currentIdGroup = id_group.shift();
pm.environment.set("id_of_group", currentIdGroup);
pm.environment.set("id_group", id_group);
```

**Tests:**

```
var id_group = pm.environment.get("id_group");
console.log(id_group);
if (id_group && id_group.length > 0) {
   postman.setNextRequest('Add user to groups');
} else {
   postman.setNextRequest();
}
```

**Data.json file:**

```
[{
 "id_user":47091,
 "id_group":"14803,14805"
}]
```

Comment: Are you getting errors? What's in the environment variable `id_group`? Looking at your data file `id_group` is not an array, it's a string so you would need to parse it

Comment: I didn't have errors, i was just questioning about how to do it. I discovered later pm.iterationData() which do exactly what I needed. 
Yes it was a string, so I changed the way my JSON file is generated. 
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found an answer.
In the pre-request script I use the variable id_group, this variable is used to get the id's which are going to be used in the loop.

I found *pm.iterationData.get();*, it will take the data from the JSON file. Instead of *id_group = ["14803","14805"];* I use *pm.iterationData("id_group")*.

My pre request script look like this now:

```
var id_group = pm.environment.get("id_group");   

    if (!id_group) {
        id_group = pm.iterationData.get("id_group");
    } 

    var currentIdGroup = id_group.shift();
    pm.environment.set("id_of_group", currentIdGroup);
    pm.environment.set("id_group", id_group);
```

And I cheat a little, my JSON look like this now:

```
[{
 "id_user":47091,
 "id_group":["14803","14805"]
}]
```

Comment: What about reading a JSON file from a pre-request script without using the collection runner?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an Array-Object. But the `pm.environment.set()` stores only strings.
You must convert them into strings with `JSON.stringify()`.

Instead of `pm.environment.set("id_of_group", currentIdGroup);` i would suggest

```
pm.environment.set("id_of_group", JSON.stringify(currentIdGroup));
```

And backwards the same. If you are loading from the env vars, you have to parse your stringified objects:
`JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("id_group"));`

Comment: It could be a great idea too. I have find an other way but I will try with stringify, just curiosity. Thank you !